# Why does changing the minSdkVersion of my application change the color of the text in my tabs?

Tags: java, android

Why does changing the minSdkVersion of my application change the color of the text in my tabs? Am I doing something wrong?

I recreated the problem using the [Hello Tab Widget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). By adding
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />`
to the manifest, I get ugly tabs. If I don't want ugly tabs, do I have to change the minSdkVersion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the minSdkVersion specifies that what minimum level of android version is to be used to show the UI of the application. It doesn't mean that first look for higher version, so your application is using the minimum version that you specified. And the version level is responsible for the UI VIEW.

Comment: Ok. I guess I was confused because the newer SDK versions don't look as nice as the older ones.